# Split a string of numbers into long variables

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a string variable which I want to split into 3 variables.

```
String = "2,3,4";
```

I am trying to split these up into three Long variables. Essentially all I want is to parse the string into three long variables.

```
Long one = 
Long two =
Long three =
```

Just wondering how can I do this ?
I do not want to place them into a list.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: `String[] parts = "2,3,4".split(",")`, then use `parts[0]`, `parts[1]`, etc. and parse them to `Long` with `Long.parseLong`

Comment: use a `Scanner` like in `var sc = new Scanner(string).useDelimiter(",")` and `sc.nextLong()` to read each `long` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, first split the String by ,(comma)  with the help of `split` method ,this will return a String array then access the array index by typecasting elements to `long`.

```
        String s = "2,3,4";
        
        String [] splitS = s.split(",");
        
        long nr = Long.parseLong(splitS[0]);
        long nrTwo = Long.parseLong(splitS[1]);
        long nrThree = Long.parseLong(splitS[2]);
```

Or if you don't know how many element will `s` contain then should create a list of Long

```
List<Long> longNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then iterate through the String by splitting them by, typecasting the element then adding in the list

```
 for(String s : numbers.split(",")){
            longNumbers.add(Long.parseLong(s));
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a list  of longs

```
List<Long> longs = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then store each value in the list

```
for(String s: string.split(",")) {
   longs.add(Long.parseLong(s));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `java.util.Scanner` (*"A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types"*)

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(string).useDelimiter(",");

long one = scanner.nextLong();
long two = scanner.nextLong();
long three = scanner.nextLong();
```

if a number is missing it will throw `NoSuchElementException`
if one is not in a valid format, `InputMismatchException`

The method `hasNextLong()` can be used to check if there is a well-format `long` available and `next()` can be used to read that value (to ignore it or use in an error message).

Official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) for more details.

<sub>Note 1: I used `long` (primitive type) but should work with `Long` (wrapper object, if needed)</sub>
<sub>Note 2: to ignore white spaces before/after the comma use delimiter like  `...useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*")`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Using Streams:

```
List<Long> longNumbers = List.of( "2,3,4".split( "," ) ).stream().map( num -> Long.parseLong( num ) ).collect( toList() );

longNumbers.get(0)
longNumbers.get(1)
longNumbers.get(2)
```

Comment: *"I do not want to place them into a list"*, so I would prefer `Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream("2,3,4").mapToLong(Long::parseLong).toArray();`  ((or at least `Arrays.stream("2,3,4").split(","))...` no need of a List just to create a stream of an array))